# upload (backup) to cloud from commandline?

Tags: command-line, backup, upload, cloud-storage

Is there any free and established (that is not trashy and prone to go away any day) cloud service that I can upload files to ?

I need this for daily backup of some small amount of essential data from my computer that can be then accessed from anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by free? As in free beer or free speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 is gaining ground for this purpose. There are [a number of tools people have written](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/007641.html) for automating backups to S3 via command line.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's S3 service seems quite reliable.

You didn't mention which OS you want a command-line tool for, but boto (http://code.google.com/p/boto/) provides python libraries (and command-line tools) for accessing S3 written in python (so they should work on most platforms)